# Unable to view my drives while installing pop!_os

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, dualboot, pop-os

I am trying to dual boot windows with pop!_os, and after i restart my laptop with the boot USB inserted(which contains pop) [gparted does not show any drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w2A4.jpg) , just the USB. (I have a 1 TB NVMe SSD)

Answer (score 0):

You’re viewing the USB flash drive’s partition map. In the upper right part of the application, you can select the drive to operate on. Yours will probably be called `nvme0n1`. GParted allows you to operate on a single drive at a time.